# Netsuite saved search in scheduled script throws error SSS_SEARCH_TIMEOUT

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

Netsuite allows users to import CSV without script processing and I can't control it.

To capture such records I scheduled a script after midnight that searches for all the Customer Payments that were imported during the previous day using the following code:

```
newlyCreateTran = search.create({
    type: 'transaction',
    filters:
        [
            ["type", "anyof", "CustPymt"],
            "AND",
            ["mainline", "is", "T"],
            'AND',
            ["systemnotes.context", "anyof", "CSV"],
            "AND",
            ["systemnotes.type", "is", "T"],
            "AND",
            ["subsidiary.internalid", "anyof", pf_subsidiary[p]],
            "AND",
            ["systemnotes.date", "within", "yesterday"],
            "AND",
            // this line is required in case the script will run out of remaining usage in one go, so I can resume during next run.
            ["internalidnumber", 'greaterthan', parseInt(csv_cm_res[0].getValue({name: 'custrecord_pf_hqm_recid'}))]
        ],
    columns:
        [
            new search.createColumn({name: 'subsidiary'}),
            new search.createColumn({
                name: 'internalid',
                sort: search.Sort.ASC
            })
        ]
});

var results = newlyCreateTran.run();
var resultslice = results.getRange({start: 0, end: 500});
return resultslice;
```

Users of one subsidiary imported 2k+ records during the day and my script is timing out when querying from that subsidiary after 5 minutes.
[image]

How do I prevent time out from happening? How to optimise the query?

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend you to try creating this Saved Search in NetSuite UI and running the same. I've faced similar issue and this usually happens when the conditions in Criteria are somewhat complex.

I am not sure but I think the following line is causing the issue. Can you please test once without this line?

```
["internalidnumber", 'greaterthan', parseInt(csv_cm_res[0].getValue({name: 'custrecord_pf_hqm_recid'}))]
```

If yes, you can always pass this value as a filter to your Saved Search. [For this you'll have to load the Saved Search using `search.load` and use Search filters].

Let me know how it goes in comments below.

Answer (score 0):

> Netsuite allows users to import CSV without script processing ***and I
> can't control it.***

I'd like to challenge this assumption.  There may be some specific reason in your case why you cannot control it, but NetSuite provides a permission specifically for this. It's called "Control SuiteScript and Workflow Trigger per CSV Import" and can be found in the Setup subtab under the Permissions tab of the Role definition page.  If this permission is removed from a role which has "Import CSV File" permission, any user with that role will still be able to run CSV imports, but the "Run Server SuiteScripts" checkbox will be checked and greyed out - the user will not be able to deselect it.

Comment: This is interesting and I didn't know about it, will it also work for the pre-existing saved imports?

Comment: I haven't tested it on a saved import definition, but it wouldn't be hard to verify.  Modify the relevant role and assign it to yourself, then run through the import wizard to verify.  If the Run Server SuiteScripts box is ***un***checked and greyed out, you could switch back to Administrator role, go through the import wizard again and check the box, then save the import definition again at the end of the wizard.  HTH.

Comment: I just checked. Removing this permission disables the option in saved searches - saved search value remans - if it was disabled it remains disabled. I just checked and the client has 30,000 saved searches. How do I migrate those?

Comment: Saved searches?  This permission setting shouldn't affect saved searches...did you mean saved CSV import settings?  If I assume you mean saved import settings, 30,000 sounds like like far too many, so I'm a bit unsure what you're facing!

Comment: The client has 30,000 saved CSV imports with switched off Run Server SuiteScripts. If I were to solve this problem by removing the permission, I will also need to migrate those 30,000 saved CSV imports which they use or can use. The client is quite a big organisation.

Comment: Yeah, that's a lot of saved CSV imports - even for a big organization.  I don't know of any way to programmatically update them.